# how to avoid powertop settings to roll back automatically

Tags: power-management, battery, thinkpad, tlp, powertop

I'm using powertop and tlp in ubuntu 19.10 in my thinkpad x380 yoga.
The battery drains pretty quick so I'm using powertop and tlp to monitor and manage power consumption.

The problem is that every time I open powertop I see *VM writeback timeout* and *Autosuspend USB device Pen and multitouch...* labelled as Bad.

From tlpui I see enabled the autosuspend for USB and the VM writeback timeout set to 15 seconds (powertop writes 1500 ms so it should be fine)

What am I missing so I can leave these settings always good?

Is there any other recommendation that I can use to improve my battery lifetime in this machine besides powertop and ltp / ltpui?

EDIT: from powetop:

```
          Usage Device name
         53.0%        CPU misc
         53.0%        CPU core
        100.0%        Radio device: iwlwifi
        100.0%        Radio device: thinkpad_acpi
        100.0%        Radio device: btusb
         51.0%        Display backlight
          4.3 pkts/s  Network interface: wlp4s0 (iwlwifi)
```

Answer (score 2):

Powertop's recommendations are very schematic, they do not take into account frequently occurring problems with certain types of devices.

For that reason TLP's settings deviate from powertop's recommendations for a few but important exceptions

Refer to:

- https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#usb
- https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#powertop

USB Autosuspend: Input devices like mice and keyboards as well as scanners handled by libsane are exluded by default – this saves you the hassle of malfunctioning devices

VM writeback timeout: Powertop insists on a value of 1500 centisecs, whereas TLP's defaults are 1500 on AC and 6000 on battery power. If you incline towards powertop's opinion then change your config file to: `MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=15` Otherwise just ignore it.

[Disclaimer: I'm TLP's author]